# Demonstration for rotation algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, rotation

In many places I see array rotation for the range `[begin, end)` with "middle point" `m` implemented as:

```
void rotate(begin, m, end)
    reverse(begin, end);
    reverse(begin, m);
    reverse(m, end)
```

where reverse function is the equivalent of `std::reverse` and this works fine. The standard library algorithm `std::rotate` goes even further, making the rotation only with `forward_iterators` (reverse need `bidirectional_iterators`).

**Do you know where I can find the formal demonstration for the rotation algorithms or can you please explain it to me here if there is a simple demonstration that can fit in SO answer?**

Comment: Not sure what you are asking - how it works, or why is it needed?

Comment: How it works and the mathematical proof that it is correct

Comment: Here are some example algorithms: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-rotation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a nice video about this on youtube. The rotation is better explained than it was in Elements of Programming where a dumb guy like me just didn't get it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7v3WRYLXjfI&index=11&list=PLHxtyCq_WDLW0NqZCcrrQUa24H_af6Mrn

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to offer a visual proof.

Consider a string like this:

```
begin----->m--->end
```

Applying `reverse(begin, end)` will result in:

```
begin<---m<-----end
```

Applying `reverse(begin, m)` will result in:

```
begin--->m<-----end
```

And finally `reverse(m, end)` will lead to:

```
begin--->m----->end
```

Thus rotating the string.

Answer (score 2):

Think about that axis point `m`:

```
begin----->m-1,m,m+1----->end-1
```

after `reverse(begin, end)`:

```
end-1----->m+1,m,m-1----->begin
```

after `reverse(begin, m)`:

```
m+1----->end-1,m,m-1----->begin
```

after `reverse(m, end)`:

```
m+1----->end-1,begin----->m-1,m
```

thus rotating `begin`...`m` to the last places and rotating `m+1`...`end-1` to the first places.